# Issues creating new app bundle on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, app-bundle

I have two paid apps on iTunes Connect and I wish to create a new app bundle including both apps.

However, when I select the first app on the 'New App Bundle' page, the second app simply disappears from the 'Apps in This Bundle' and I can't select it.

Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you. create an app bundle by creating a separate iTunes Connect record for it, just as you did to create the records for the individual apps. On My Apps, **click the plus sign and select**  Create Bundle to bring up the Create Bundle page.

please refer this [for more details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BundlingApps.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I realize very well how to get to the 'Create Bundle' page... however, my issue is that once I add an app on this page, the other app disappears, as if the apps are not compatible.